# Implementing React-Datagrid with Play Framework

Tags: reactjs, playframework, sbt, webjars

I'm trying to render a table in a Play project using the React-datagrid library imported from WebJars. When I run the project however, I get these problems:

1. "Warning: React can't find the root component node for data-reactid value `.0.1.1`. If you're seeing this message, it probably means that you've loaded two copies of React on the page. At this time, only a single copy of React can be loaded at a time."
2. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of undefined"

Here's the code for rendering the table:

```
var data = [
    {id: 0, index: 1, firstName: 'John', city: 'Toronto', email: '123@hotmail.com'}
];

var columns = [
    { name: 'index', title: '#', width: 50 },
    { name: 'firstName' },
    { name: 'lastName'  },
    { name: 'city' },
    { name: 'email' }
];

var App = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return <DataGrid
            idProperty='id'
            dataSource={data}
            columns={columns}
            style={{height: 500}}
        />
    }
})

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("testTable"));
```

These are the scripts I'm referencing in the HTML file:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(WebJarAssets.fullPath("react", "dist/react.js"))'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(WebJarAssets.fullPath("react-dom", "dist/react-dom.js"))'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(WebJarAssets.fullPath("react-datagrid", "dist/react-datagrid.js"))'></script>
```

This is what I have in my build.sbt:

```
"org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.4.0-1",
"org.webjars.npm" % "react-datagrid" % "2.0.1",
"org.webjars.bower" % "react-d3" % "0.2.2"
```

Here is the link to the example of the datagrid I'm following:
http://zippyui.com/react-datagrid/#/examples/basic

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `dist/react-datagrid.js` has everything it needs to run pre-packed into it including another `React`. Remove the other react scripts or find a build of `react-datagrid` that doesn't bundle `React`.

Comment: When I remove the other scripts such that I only have react-datagrid.js, I get that React and ReactDOM are undefined, so that means that I'm not loading React twice?

Comment: odd - if you look at the source for [`dist/react-datagrid.js`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zippyui/react-datagrid/master/dist/react-datagrid.js) it looks like it defines `React`. I may be looking at the wrong src.

Comment: Yeah, also when I view the external libraries in the project navigator in intellij, I have access react and react-dom jars; it was made available when I included datagrid in the build.sbt